# How do I do in memory Web API test with attribute routing?

Tags: testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting, in-memory

There seems to be a lot of help around if you do 'normal' routing to your Web Api Controllers.

I am exclusively using attribute routing. I would like to set up in memory tests to allow us much testing from "url" to "response" as possible.

Ideally I would not pollute my solution with third party helpers grabbed from Nuget. Is it possible to do these tests with the 'standard' packages?